# Можно ли в img внутри alt="" сделать зачеркнутый текст?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, img

Можно ли в `img` внутри `alt=""` сделать зачеркнутый текст?

Почему-то думала, что в `alt` и `title` используется `markdown`, но две подряд тильды желаемого не дают:

```html
<img src="img/slider.jpg" alt="Наш товар. Старая цена: ~~200₽~~ Новая цена: 100₽"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```html
<p><a href="page/lorem.html"><img src="" 
  width="120" height="120" alt="̶г̶л̶а̶в̶н̶а̶я̶ ̶с̶т̶р̶а̶н̶и̶ц̶а̶ ̶g̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶"></a></p>
```

Comment: В символе зачёркивания перед «г» нет необходимости